# breezejs - how to refresh a sub entity

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, breeze

How can I force breeze to refresh a sub entity?

My DB has been updated by a other application / site (not from breeze). Now i know on javascript level, when this happend. But i dont want to refresh the hole object / entity with all sub entities. What I want to update is only a (sub) entity with a specific attribute (like account -> id === '3'), but it can be the needed entity isn't cached locally.

```
 user-entity
   -- accounts
   ----account 2
   ----account 3   <--- update this entity
   ----......
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand the problem.  Why not simply execute a query for subobjects with 'accountId == 3'?. This will overwrite any existing entities in the local cache that have matching entity keys to the entities returned from the query. i.e. refreshing these entities.

Perhaps I'm not understanding the question.